# @Published property in singleton not emitting events after the first one

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, swiftui, combine

I have a `@Published` property in a singleton class which is observed in a view model class and it only received the first initial value and not after that. Why?

View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel(singletonService: SingletonService.shared)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Text("Hello World")
            }.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Increase Number", action: {
                SingletonService.shared.increaseNumber()
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
import Combine

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init(
        singletonService: SingletonService
    ) {
        let cencellable = singletonService.$number.sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
        // Never called after the first time
    }

}
```

Singleton

```
import Combine

class SingletonService {

    static let shared = SingletonService()

    @Published var number = 0

    func increaseNumber() {
        number += 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscription lives until subscriber is alive, but in this your case

```
let cencellable = singletonService.$number.sink(receiveValue: { print($0)
```

subscriber is destroyed right out of context. It should be like

```
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init(singletonService: SingletonService) {
     singletonService.$number
        .sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```